# Ruby on Rails filtering attributes on returning model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an API for a Rails app and I want to return `User` objects for an API call but without `crypted_password`, `salt`, or `login_token` attributes.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
do api_fetch_user(u)
  user=User.find(u)
  return user(:filter=>"crypted_password", "salt", "login_token")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work in your case, i haven't tried that personally though.
Try to reset the Filtered Attributes to nil before returning the Object.

```
do api_fetch_user(u)
   user=User.find(u)
   user.crypted_password = ''
   user.salt = ''
   user.login_token = ''
   return user
end
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. It still returns the attributes, but as empty strings. I wonder if there's anything like Hash.delete(:attribute)?

Comment: you might wanna try this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002898  It seems you can achieve what you desire by using user.delete("crypted_password")

Answer (score 3):

```rails
def api_fetch_user(user)
  user.attributes.select { |key,v| AVAILABLE_USER_FIELDS.include?(key) }
end
```

Comment: There is an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #<Array:0x5190258>. Or for<relation> with scoped.

Comment: Because you should pass a model instance, not an array here. If u got an array of the users, for example, the call should look like `users.each { |u| api_fetch_user(u) }`