# Rails - creating an API and filtering attributes on an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

My question is very similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259429/ruby-on-rails-filtering-attributes-on-returning-model-object). However, I am creating an API in Rails 4 and my API base controller inherits from ActionController::Base

```
classApi::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
```

Since this controller is not inheriting from ActionRecord I can not use something like `select` or `except` to get the attributes I want from the object.

My goal is, instead of returning the full object when the API is called:

```
 {"id":1,"user_id":1,"name":"foo","description":"bar"}
```

I want to return this (but still have multiple attributes):

```
 {"name":"foo","description":"bar"}
```

**Controller:**

```
 class Api::V1::ProjectsController < Api::V1::BaseController
   def create
     @project = Project.new(project_params)
     @project.user = User.find(1)
     if @project.save
       respond_with(@project, :location => api_v1_project_path(@project))
     else
       respond_with(@project)
     end
    end  
   end

private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name)
  end 

end
```

Comment: place your controller code please.

Comment: Is this a normal ActiveRecord object? Why shouldn't you be able to use the ActiveRecord methods on it then? Or are you talking about some hash or array of hashes from some other data source?

Comment: @thorstenmüller yes, it is a normal ActiveRecord object. If I try to use @object.select(:name) I get the following error `NoMethodError (private method 'select' called for ...`

Comment: As NitinJ says, please add the code of your controller, this seems to be a different issue than you think it is. You should be able to use ActiveRecord as everywhere else. (No controller inherits from AcrtiveRecord)

Comment: `@object.name` will work or do something like this `Model.select(:filed_name).first`

Comment: @NitinJ thanks. Why does `Model.select(:name).first` work and `@project.select(:name)` not work?

Comment: @diasks2 because you are trying to put that on active record object rather than on class :)

Comment: @NitinJ `@object.name` works, however I updated my question…I actually need to return multiple attributes, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with `Model.select(:name).first`

or for selecting multiple attributes do

```
 Model.select('email, id').first
```

you can also use Jbuilder gem for rendering json and gives you full control whatever you want to return

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However if I do `Model.select(:name, :description).first` my return is `[{"name":"foo","description":"bar","id":null}]` while what I need is `{"name":"foo","description":"bar"}`. If I do @project the return is `{"id":1,"user_id":1,"name":"foo","description":"bar"}`

Comment: you can use Jbuilder gem for json so you will not get blocked because of this

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Jbuilder solved what I needed to do. I think it might be helpful for future SO visitors to add that piece to your answer. Thanks again!